# Raspberry Pi 4 - Not booting custom kernel

Tags: boot, boot-issues, kernel

I am running the latest Raspbian build (Buster).
I have compiled a kernel with audit/apparmor support and am trying to boot my Raspberry Pi 4 from it.
The kernel is compiled from the latest branch cloned from the GitHub repository.
This is resulting in a repeated error during boot:

> [x.xxxxxx] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Coherent DMA mask 0xffffffff (pfn 0xfff40000-0x40000) covers a smaller range of system memory than the DMA zone pfn 0x0-0x80001

I also get other errors I do not understand the cause of:

> [x.xxxxxx] bcm2835-cpureq:bcm2835_cpufreq_get_clock:93: Failed to get clock (-12)
>
> [x.xxxxxx] bcm2835_cpufreq: min=0 max=0
>
> [x.xxxxxx] raspberrypi-exp-gpio soc:firmware:gpio: Failed to get GPIO 2 config (-12 82)
>
> [x.xxxxxx] leds-gpio: probe of leds failed with error -12

It ends up hanging after just over a total of 3 seconds into boot with the error:

> [x.xxxxxx] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...

What can cause these type of errors?

Comment: Did you try to build a kernel with no modifications whatsoever? Did it boot?

Comment: I did, results are identical

Comment: Identical as in "the kernel is identical and works fine" or as in "I get the same error"?

Comment: As in, same errors

Comment: That indicates a problem with the toolchain you use. I suggest you edit your question, explaining how exactly you build that kernel and with what tools. E.g. some versions of GCC are known to produce broken kernels.

Comment: That would make sense. Thank you! Will update in the morning